# Determine field type lightning-record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

On a lightning-record-edit-form page, how you determine the field type(text, lookup, picklist)?
Thank you,
P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of using the [`lightning-record-edit-form` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) is that you don't need to worry about the types of any of the fields. Using `lightning-input-field` inside of the component is enough - Salesforce will handle the rest and show the appropriate UI based on the type of the field. For example, a combo box for a picklist, an `input[type="text"]`  for text, and a `textarea` for long text.

That said, there isn't any way in the `lightning-record-edit-form` component to tell what type a field is. All of the logic is handled internally to the component. Your best option is to use the `uiObjectInfoApi` module in your LWC and call [`getObjectInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to find out information about an object. `getObjectInfo` will return an [Object Info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_object_info.htm#ui_api_responses_object_info) object which will let you access metadata on the object and its fields. Follow the pattern in the example below.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    accountObjectInfo({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            console.log(data.fields['Name'].dataType); //String
            console.log(data.fields['Fax'].dataType); //Phone
            console.log(data.fields['AccountSource'].dataType); //Picklist
            console.log(data.fields['NumberOfEmployees'].dataType); //Int
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That really depends on your other component, but in general yes. Can you ask a new question or update your question with more clarity?

Comment: Thanks for the reply nbrown.  I am trying to add a custom LWC to the html based on the field type.

Comment: I would post your code and more of an explanation of what you want to do.